# increase class proportion in a class proportion vector without changing the sum of the vector

Tags: r, sampling

Say I have a vector **x** which defines the number of samples in a given class:

```
x <- c(250,362,10,246,30)
```

In this case, there are five classes. 
The resulting class proportion vector is given by:

```
    p <- x/sum(x)
[1] 0.27839644 0.40311804 0.01113586 0.27394209 0.03340757
```

How to update this class proportion vector so that class has proportion of at least 0.05? 
An additional constraint is that the proportions to be removed from the classes > 0.05 will be evenly distributed to the all classes is larger or equal to 0.05.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the following lines of code may do what you are after.

```
# Your vector
x <- c(250,362,10,246,30)
# Add a name tag
names(x) <- seq(1, length(x))
print(x)
  1   2   3   4   5
250 362  10 246  30

# The new "collapsed" vector
x.new <- x
names(x.new) <- names(x)

# Remove entries with less than 5% of sum, and distribute them
# evenly (as per request) across the other entries.
# Note that the order in which you do this obviously matters:
# Omitting a sub-5% entry from position i may lead to an original
# sub-5% entry at j>i that is now above the 5% threshold and won't
# get omitted. 
for (i in 1:length(x.new)) {
    if (!is.na(x.new[i]) & x.new[i]/sum(x.new) < 0.05) {
        x.new[-i] <- x.new[-i] + x.new[i] / length(x.new[-i])
        x.new <- x.new[-i]
    }
}
print(x.new)
       1        2        4
263.3333 375.3333 259.3333

# Or print as fraction
print(x.new/sum(x.new))
        1         2         4
0.2932442 0.4179659 0.2887899
```

Note that the order matters (see my comment in the code). You can check that `sum(x) == sum(x.new)` and `x.new/sum(x.new) > 0.05`.